# How does default scope works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How does the default scope work?

For example, I have in my model:

```
  default_scope -> { includes(:translations) }
```

This is my model:

```
class MyModel
 default_scope -> { includes(:translations) }

 has_many: translations
end
```

I know about that default scope can do some default job, for example sort by column.

But how it works with `include`?

Comment: Why not just try it in the console?

Answer (score 2):

The method `includes` was designed to solve N + 1 query problem. For example, if you have a model:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :translations
end
```

Then this code

```
MyModel.limit(50).each do |model|
  model.translations.each do |translation|
    # ...
  end
end
```

generates 51 queries to your database: one query to fetch 50 records from `my_models` table, and 50 queries to fetch `translations` for each of these models. This affects the performance of the application dramatically.

To fix it the code could be rewritten as:

```
MyModel.includes(:translations).limit(50).each do |model|
...
```

With `includes` Rails generates only 2 SQL query. First one fetches 50 `my_models` records, and second query fetches `translations` for those `my_models`.

Having `default_scope -> { includes(:translations) }` just let you skip writing `includes(:translations)` in the situations described above. Even if you write

```
MyModel.limit(50).each do |model|
...
```

Rails will do 2 queries since translations are included by default scope.

I need to add that [default_scope](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope) has some non-obvious pitfalls, and it's [not](https://andycroll.com/ruby/dont-use-default-scope/) [recommended](https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/) by some developers.